# Populating the listview with different lists

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add information from 3 different list objects to a listview on the form divided into 3 columns. The lists are generated in another class (part of the Business Layer) and I'm trying to display them under one listview on the main form. I'm not 100% sure if this is even possible.

Here is where the lists are generated:

```
public List<Job> SelectPendngJobs() // get a list of all pending jobs
    {
        JobDH jobDH = new JobDH();
        return jobDH.SelectAllPendingJobs();
    }

    public List<Job> SelectInProgressJobs() // get a list of all in progress jobs
    {
        JobDH jobDH = new JobDH();
        return jobDH.SelectAllPendingJobs();
    }

    public List<Job> SelectFinishedJobs() // get a list of all finished jobs
    {
        JobDH jobDH = new JobDH();
        return jobDH.SelectAllFinishedJobs();
    }
```

Here is how I'm trying to implement it in the main form:

```
private void frmJobsManagement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Job JB = new Job();

        var myList = new List<List<PremiereSolutionProject.BLL.Job>>()
        {
            JB.SelectPendngJobs(),
            JB.SelectInProgressJobs(),
            JB.SelectFinishedJobs()
        };

        lstJobTracker.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (var row in myList)
        {
            var item = new ListViewItem(lstJobTracker.Items.Count.ToString());
            item.SubItems.AddRange(row);
            lstJobTracker.Items.Add(item);
        }
        lstJobTracker.EndUpdate();


    }
```

**This is the error I'm getting is a compiler error (CS1503):**

'System.Collections.Generic.List<PremiereSoluionProject.BLL.Job>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSubItem[]'

Please help?

Comment: the error is coming from `item.SubItems.AddRange(row);` -- you can't add that via that method. you need to convert `row` to `ListViewSubItem` array. You could do something like `item.SubItems.AddRange(row.Select(x => new ListViewSubItem(x.ThePropertyYouWantToShow)));`

Comment: See codeproject for samples of ListView : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2